# Python : in a text file, how to group lines previously duplicated according to pattern?

Tags: python

I have this text file - tasks followed by tags between parentheses - :

```
Buy a new tablet (@urgent, @finance, @internet)
Pay my rent (@home, @finance, @urgent, @important)
Watch TV (@home, @internet)
Do some exercise (@health, @important)
```

How can I in Python get the following view of this text file :

```
 @finance
    Buy a new tablet 
    Pay my rent 

 @health
    Do some exercise

@home
    Pay my rent
    Watch TV 

@important
    Pay my rent 
    Do some exercise 

@internet
    Buy a new tablet 
    Watch TV 

@urgent
    Pay my rent
```

I simply do not know how to proceed (btw, this is not homework). There are innumerable topics about deleting duplicate lines, but I could not find topics examining this specific question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I simply do not know how to proceed..."*. We too face the same difficulty. Why was `'health'` chosen first, `'home'` second,...? Or does order necessarily matter? What have you atleast tried?

Comment: @Austin : I edited my question to make it more legible ; I wish the order to be alphabetical ; I know how to count the number of @ pattern in a line, of course, and that is about as far as I can get. Thanks anyway

Comment: Shouldn't `'finance'` come first as per alphabetical order?

Comment: @Austin : Yes of course, sorry for this stupid mistake ;-) I edit again…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient way, but works for good:

```
lst = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        mid = line.split('(')
        all_ats = mid[1][:-1].split(', ')
        lst.append((mid[0].strip(), all_ats))

vals = sorted(set(y for x in lst for y in x[1]))

for x in vals:
    print(x)
    for y, z in lst:
        if x in z:
            print(f'\t{y}')

'''
@finance
    Buy a new tablet
    Pay my rent
@health
    Do some exercise
@home
    Pay my rent
    Watch TV
@important
    Pay my rent
    Do some exercise
@internet
    Buy a new tablet
    Watch TV
@urgent
    Buy a new tablet
    Pay my rent
'''
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works superbly (I use iOS Pythonista) ; I must nevertheless confess I do not understand all the magic at work, but it works ! I shall now try to export it to iOS Editorial (same developer). Again, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the first word of each line as the key to a dict, and make the associated value in the dict a list so you can append to it. Without any frills, and WARNING untested code:

```
mydict = {}

for line in file:
    key = line.split(' ')[0]
    if key not in mydict:
         mydict[key] = [ line ]
    else:
         mydict[key].append(line)

for key, value in mydict.items() :
     print(key)
     for line in value:
          print( '    ' + line )
     print(' ')
```

There are lots of ways to make this shorter and arguably more Pythonic. I've written it in what I believe is the easiest way to understand without using any 'extras', for example using vanilla `{}` rather than anything in `collections`.

Note - question has been altered, do not have time to rewrite this answer. See comments. I hope the gist of this may be useful to someone.

Comment: both thanks and sorry : while you were answering my question, I was editing it… Does that change your answer ? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it does.The conceptsyou'll use are still the same, a dict of lists. For each line you'll now have to separate the part before the brackets from the list of things starting with '@' in brackets, then split it up and remove commas. For each @thing as key, proceed as per my example.

Comment: Thank you ; although your answer is not what I was waiting for precisely (order by @tag), this will be definitely useful for another problem I have in mind. Thanks again